# Norm estimate of pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If $A$ is a $m\times n$-matrix, with independent columns, then the pseudoinverse $A^{+}$ of $A$ is $(A^{*} A)^{-1} A^{*}$.
Does anyboady know whether it is possible to estimate the norm of $A^{+}$ by the one of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it already fails in the scalar case: The inverse of $\varepsilon$ is $1/\varepsilon$.